# How can I use Doctrine Native Query to order results by the count of a join with a conditional statement?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-3.4

I want to select the rows from the `poll` table and order them by the count or sum of rows of a joined `vote` table where `vote.is_current_vote = true`.

The Vote table tracks all votes but only the latest per user is ever counted in the poll, which is marked as `is_current_vote`.

I'm struggling to work out how to get the count of the Vote table using either Doctrine Query Builder or Native Query.

Here is the database structure:

```
create table if not exists user
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    username varchar(45) not null,
    slug varchar(45) not null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    updated_at datetime null,
    constraint UNIQ_8D93D649989D9B62
        unique (slug),
    constraint UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677
        unique (username)
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci
;

create table if not exists poll
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id int null,
    question varchar(140) not null,
    slug varchar(140) not null,
    is_active tinyint(1) not null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    updated_at datetime null,
    constraint UNIQ_84BCFA45989D9B62
        unique (slug),
    constraint FK_84BCFA45A76ED395
        foreign key (user_id) references user (id)
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci
;

create index IDX_84BCFA45A76ED395
    on poll (user_id)
;

create table if not exists vote
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    poll_id int not null,
    user_id int not null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    is_current_vote tinyint(1) not null,
    constraint FK_5A1085643C947C0F
        foreign key (poll_id) references poll (id),
    constraint FK_5A108564A76ED395
        foreign key (user_id) references user (id),
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci
;

create index IDX_5A1085643C947C0F
    on vote (poll_id)
;

create index IDX_5A108564A76ED395
    on vote (user_id)
;
```

I have this query working in MySQL, which gives me the data I want:

```
select poll.id, poll.slug, poll.question, poll.created_at,
       u.id, u.username, u.slug, u.profile_picture,
       sum(case when v.is_current_vote = true then 1 else 0 end) as total_votes
from poll
       left join user u on poll.user_id = u.id
       left join vote v on poll.id = v.poll_id
group by poll.id
order by total_votes desc
```

The data should be ordered by the count of votes where "v.is_current_vote=true".
Example Data (omitting some columns above so it's easier to read):

```
poll.question, u.username, total_votes  
Is Elvis Alive?, someone, 15  
Is the future bright?, someone_else, 10  
Is this all a dream?, another_user, 5
```

Is it possible do something like that in Symfony/Doctrine QueryBuilder statement or do I have to use Native SQL? I can't work out how to do it with either. I'd be very grateful for some guidance.

This is my current Native SQL Attempt, I get rows from the `poll` table but both vote and user are `null`:

```
/**
 * Class PollRepository
 * @package PollBundle\Repository
 */
class PollRepository extends EntityRepository
{

 /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\NativeQuery
     */
    public function findPopular()
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('PollBundle\Entity\Poll', 'poll');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('PollBundle\Entity\User', 'u', 'poll', 'user', [
            'id' => 'user_id',
            'slug' => 'user_slug',
            'created_at' => 'user_created_at',
            'updated_at' => 'user_updated_at',
            'is_active' => 'user_is_active',
        ]);
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('PollBundle\Entity\Vote', 'v', 'poll', 'votes', [
            'id' => 'vote_id',
            'user_id' => 'vote_user_id',
            'created_at' => 'vote_created_at',
            'updated_at' => 'vote_updated_at',
        ]);

        $sql = '
            SELECT poll.id, poll.slug, poll.question, poll.created_at,
                   u.id, u.username, u.slug, u.profile_picture,
                   sum(case when v.is_current_vote = true then 1 else 0 end) as total_votes
            from poll
                   left join user u on poll.user_id = u.id
                   left join vote v on poll.id = v.poll_id
            group by poll.id
            order by total_votes desc
        ';

        return $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the link I haven't read that before. Are you asking that I provide clearer table definitions and examples of expected rows, or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sarcoma You can provide a basic table structure (showing only relevant columns for the problem at hand here); some minimal sample data which can reproduce your case, and expected output. Note that you may not provide actual data value, just some sample representational values would work!

Comment: Of course, no problem. I have something sort of close (I think) using Doctrine Native Query, that'll add too.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have added SQL to create the tables I'm working with and an example of the expected output. I've left in columns, like `slug` and `created_at` as they conflict between columns.

Comment: @Strawberry I've added some additional details and information, does that help?

Comment: No. Honestly, I think the accepted answer at the linked question is entirely self-explanatory.

Comment: @Strawberry ha, oh well. Apparently not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something similar to this query? [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html) can do nearly everything SQL can do.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
   ->select('p.question, u.username, count(v.isCurrentVote) AS votes')
   // joins maybe need change depending on your relations
   ->leftJoin('p.user', 'u')
   ->leftJoin('p.votes', 'v')
   ->groupBy('p.id')
   ->orderBy('votes');
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: It's close, I'll have a play about to see what's happening. I've changed the votes to an `innerJoin` as the results were all over the place when I tried it as is.

Comment: I think I'll be able to use it, but the results are like: `0 => 0 => Poll {}, "votes" => "4"]`, so it has an additional associative array that I don't want. I want it flattened somehow. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Try removing 'AS votes' and replace 'votes' inside the->orderBy with the result colum number.

Comment: It would be useful to have the count to display. I'm not sure what you mean by "replace 'votes' inside the->orderBy with the result column number"

Comment: Can you put the result somewhere and explain what you need to be changed?

Comment: I kind of want to have votes attached as a field on the polls entity. But I think I'll have to live with it as is. I got the long from Native Query working and ended up with exactly what the QueryBuilder achieved in 7 lines! Thanks for the help, it'll do the trick. I might look into prepared statements next to see if they offer a solution.

Comment: You could also create a function inside your Poll class like getVotes() { $count = 0; foreach($this->votes as $vote) { if ($vote->getIsCurrentVote()) { $count += 1; } } return $count; } This would do the filtering with PHP so it might slow down your application a bit, but the votes would be attached to the poll.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I really don't want to do any extra processing. I want to get the data from the database query in the correct format. I've used native query again as I wanted to get to grips with how it works. Adding getScalarResult gets me a usable flat response, but now that's broken in the paginator that I'm using. It looks like I'll have to then write custom pagination, which shouldn't take long, It's just annoying.